# Rendered image is not as smooth as in 3d preview

Tags: rendering

I'm a newb to blender so apologies if this is obvious.  I modelled a simple cup and set the modifier subdivisions to 5 after I turned on 'smooth'.  It renders fine in the CTRL+Z render preview window but when I do a final render the handle of the cup is blocky and not smooth.... Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Attached pics of the render with blocky handle and the object/render settings

Many thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Toi have 5 subdivision levels for preview, but only two for rendering. Bring up the value so that you get more subdivision for rendering

Comment: Ahh yeah, I totally forgot! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Well, [**Cegaton**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/1853/cegaton) already found the problem, but the question needs an answer for future users.

The `Subdivision surface` modifier has two important parameters: the `view` and the `render` subdivisions. As their name suggests, `view` determines how smoothed out the surface will be when viewing it in the viewport, and `render` does the same for rendered images.
[image: Modifier]

This is useful if you want a smoother object when rendering, but want a better performance of the viewport and don't need much detail when previewing – you can set a lower `view` and a higher `render`.

**If you set the `render` parameter lower than the `view` parameter, objects will appear smoother in the viewport than in actual renders.**

Another possible cause of this problem is that the modifier is visible <sub>[image: eye]</sub> but isn't being rendered <sub>[image: camera]</sub>. In that case, click the camera icon to enable rendering of the modifier (in the image above, both rendering and viewing are enabled).